# time conversion in java

Tags: java, datetime, time, datetime-conversion

I have a code that looks like this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2013-06-03 00:00:00");
        System.out.println(date);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

it outputs: 
Mon Jun 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013
Current Date Time : 2013-06-24 12:52:04

I want to change the first date printed in first line to look like the second date printed in second line. how can I do this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot influence what the `Date#toString` method does (unless you are willing to subclass `Date`, which would not be advised). Simply put, don't rely on `Date#toString`—that's what `SimpleDateFormat` is for.

Comment: Or use JodaTime, where you can use something like `DateTime.now().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")` method for formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can see the `toString` method of the `Date` object! you will see that the `toString` outputs the `Date` object like the format bellow:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

That's why `DateFormat` comes into the party to format the `Date` object, to serve our demand of formatting it as our wish!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing yourself because you're creating a date using `SimpleDateFormat#parse` specifying a mask and it's not being "kept" after printing it, right?

The point is: no matter how you create a `Date` object, it will always use it's default mask when you print it - that is something like `Mon Jun 03 00:00:00 EDT 2013`.

If you want to change the way it's printed, you could use a `SimpleDateFormat`, just as you did in your post:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("2013-06-03 00:00:00");
dateFormat.format(date);
```

Just to be clear about it: SimpleDateFormat does not change the `date` object in any way. It's purpose is only to format and parse date objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `DateFormat` to print the first `Date` object as well.

```
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

How, `println()` prints out the `Date` object depends on how `Date.toString()` has been implemented. You cannot change the format unless you extend and override the `Date` class which obviously, isn't the right approach.

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("2013-06-03 00:00:00");

    System.out.println(date); // formats as: EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy

    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    System.out.println("Current Date Time: " +
                       dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, combine the two, no?

```
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```